# MongoDB duplicates grouped by owner

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregate

I have been using mongo for a few months and, apart from simple basic query and aggregation operations, I am not yet very familiar with aggregations..I come from a sql language ..

I have a database similar to this:

```
    {
    ownerId: "A",
    email: "a@a.com",
    phone: "333",
    current: true,
    deleted: false
  },
  {
    ownerId: "A",
    email: "b@b.com",
    phone: "444",
    current: true,
    deleted: false
  },
  {
    ownerId: "A",
    email: "b@b.com",
    phone: "555",
    current: true,
    deleted: false
  },
  {
    ownerId: "B",
    email: "a@a.com",
    phone: "333",
    current: true,
    deleted: false
  },
  {
    ownerId: "C",
    email: "a@a.com",
    phone: "333",
    current: true,
    deleted: false
  },
  {
    ownerId: "B",
    email: "a@a.eu",
    phone: "333",
    current: true,
    deleted: false
  }
```

The result that I would like to obtain is: grouped by ownerId, I want to know if that ownerId has a duplicate "email" **OR** a duplicate "phone" in its address book .. The condition is that ownerId X cannot have two or more same email or same phone.
I'm trying in various ways but I can't find the way to start either .. I would like your help ..

https://mongoplayground.net/p/D6X4WTyAIiR

The expected output (basen on this example) is similar like this:

```
[
  {
    ownerId : "A",
    emails: [
      "b@b.com"
    ],
    phones :[]
  }
]
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you please show the expected output?

Comment: added! thanks, may thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this aggregation, use:

- $facet stage to work with 2 pipelines

  - in each pipeline, $group by ownerId and either email or phone, and get the count
  - $match any that are seen more than once
- $project using $concatArrays to combine the output of the facets
- $group by ownerId, and $push the duplicates onto their respective array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$facet: {
      email: [
        {$group: {
            _id: {
              owner: "$ownerId",
              email: {$ifNull:["$email","null"]}
            },
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }},
        {$match: {count: {$gt: 1}}}
      ],
      phone: [
        {$group: {
            _id: {
              owner: "$ownerId",
              phone: {$ifNull:["$phone","null"]}
            },
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }},
        {$match: {count: {$gt: 1}}}
      ]
  }},
  {$project: {
      all: {
        $concatArrays: ["$email", "$phone"]
      }
  }},
  {$unwind: "$all"},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$all._id.owner",
      emails: {$push: "$all._id.email"},
      phones: {$push: "$all._id.phone"}
  }},
  {$project:{
      _id: 0,
      onwerId: "$_id",
      emails: 1,
      phones: 1
  }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2zYyO4g3FyC)

Comment: Many thanks Joe!! Your aggregate works perfectly, and i appreciate your explanation! I have one last question: your aggregate also counts the "phone" or the "email" IF THEY ARE PRESENT IN THE DOCUMENT (it could be not present or the phone or the email) with NULL value.
Would it be possible to exclude NULL emails or phones if they are present in the document?

Comment: In each $facet pipeline, wrap the field in $ifNull, like `email:{$ifNull:["$email","null"}}`

Comment: Edited that into the answer.

Comment: Joe, the solution you provided (and inserted into answer) doesn't work..If you go to https://mongoplayground.net/p/n4X4atv_Ikh  the A ownerId in theory it should not appear because it has no email and no duplicate phone (apart from NULLs) but it still appears in the result..why?

Comment: Because it has 2 entries with no phone number.